# Prove that $HK\le G$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H\unlhd G$ and $K\unlhd G$. Prove that $HK\le G$.

**My attempt:**

$e\in H$ and $e\in K$

So, $e\in HK$

Let $h_1k_1, h_2k_2\in HK$

How do I prove that $h_1k_1h_2k_2\in HK$?

Also, if $hk\in HK$, how do I prove that $(hk)^{-1}=k^{-1}h^{-1}\in HK$?

Comment: Use the fact that $H, K$ are normal subgroups.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $e = ee \in HK$ and let $a = h_{1}k_{1}, b= h_{2}k_{2} \in HK$.
By a subgroup criterion, it suffices to show that $ab^{-1} \in HK$. 
But $ab^{-1} = (h_{1}h_{2}^{-1})\left(h_{2}k_{1}k_{2}^{-1}h_{2}^{-1}\right) \in HK$ since $K$ is a normal subgroup.

Remark: Indeed, all you needed was that $H$ be any subgroup and $K$ be a normal subgroup.